# Catching JsonArray response with volley for android

Tags: android, arrays, android-volley

I'm trying to collect string from JsonArrayRequest but I haven't been able to do so. I'm getting error as following

> 12-24 12:55:08.534 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for shoulder
>   12-24 12:55:08.537 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
>   12-24 12:55:08.537 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
>   12-24 12:55:08.537 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at com.domainzguru.butiko.Fragments.Orders.ItemsFragment$2$1.onResponse(ItemsFragment.java:170)
>   12-24 12:55:08.537 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at com.domainzguru.butiko.Fragments.Orders.ItemsFragment$2$1.onResponse(ItemsFragment.java:163)
>   12-24 12:55:08.538 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
>   12-24 12:55:08.538 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>   12-24 12:55:08.538 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   12-24 12:55:08.538 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   12-24 12:55:08.538 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   12-24 12:55:08.538 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
>   12-24 12:55:08.538 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   12-24 12:55:08.539 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>   12-24 12:55:08.539 19626-19626/com.domainzguru.butiko W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)

This is the snippet of my code

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, ITEM_CUSTOMER_MEASUREMENTS, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();

                                String shoulder = jsonobject.getString("shoulder");
                                et_shoulder.setText(shoulder);
                                String arm_hole = jsonobject.getString("arm_hole");
                                et_arm_hole.setText(arm_hole);

                                String chest_1 = jsonobject.getString("chest_1");
                                et_chest_1.setText(chest_1);

                                String chest_2 = jsonobject.getString("chest_2");
                                et_chest_2.setText(chest_2);

                                String waist = jsonobject.getString("waist");
                                et_waist.setText(waist);

                                String hip = jsonobject.getString("hip");
                                et_hip.setText(hip);

                                String slit = jsonobject.getString("slit");
                                et_slit.setText(slit);

                                String top_length = jsonobject.getString("top_length");
                                et_top_length.setText(top_length);

                                String f_neck = jsonobject.getString("f_neck");
                                et_f_neck.setText(f_neck);

                                String b_neck = jsonobject.getString("b_neck");
                                et_b_neck.setText(b_neck);

                                String sleeve_length = jsonobject.getString("sleeve_length");
                                et_sleeve_length.setText(sleeve_length);

                                String sleeve_breadth = jsonobject.getString("sleeve_breadth");
                                et_sleeve_breadth.setText(sleeve_breadth);

                                String sleeve_type = jsonobject.getString("sleeve_type");
                                et_sleeve_type.setText(sleeve_type);

                                String hip_size = jsonobject.getString("hip_size");
                                et_hip_size.setText(hip_size);

                                String ankle = jsonobject.getString("ankle");
                                et_ankle.setText(ankle);

                                String bottom_length = jsonobject.getString("bottom_length");
                                et_bottom_length.setText(bottom_length);

                                String knee = jsonobject.getString("knee");
                                et_knee.setText(knee);

                                String bottom_breadth = jsonobject.getString("bottom_breadth");
                                et_bottom_breadth.setText(bottom_breadth);

                                String thigh = jsonobject.getString("thigh");
                                et_thigh.setText(thigh);


                                Log.d("response", "onResponse: " +shoulder +arm_hole +chest_1 +chest_2 +hip +slit +top_length +f_neck +b_neck +sleeve_length
                                        +sleeve_breadth +sleeve_type +hip_size +ankle +bottom_length +knee +bottom_breadth +thigh);


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                    headers.put("Authorization", api_token);
                    headers.put("X-Request-ID", cust_id);
                    headers.put("X-Requested-With", item_type);

                    Log.d("heade values", "getHeaders: " +api_token+" "+cust_id+" "+item_type);
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            //Creating request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ItemsFragment.this.getActivity());

            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the code.This is how the response from server looks like

> [
>     {
>       "id": 3,
>       "order_id": 3,
>       "employee_id": 1,
>       "item_type": 8,
>       "shoulder": "",
>       "arm_hole": "",
>       "chest_1": "",
>       "chest_2": "",
>       "waist": "",
>       "hip": "",
>       "slit": "",
>       "top_length": "",
>       "f_neck": "",
>       "b_neck": "",
>       "sleeve_length": "",
>       "sleeve_breadth": "",
>       "sleeve_type": "",
>       "hip_size": "38",
>       "ankle": "",
>       "bottom_length": "70",
>       "knee": "",
>       "bottom_breadth": "60",
>       "thigh": "",
>       "description": "test ",
>       "amount": 5000,
>       "created_at": "2016-12-22 06:38:01",
>       "updated_at": "2016-12-22 06:38:01",
>       "customer_id": 1,
>       "item_id": 3
>     }
>   ]

Comment: @Panveet Singh I have updated the error details Jsonrequest is trigerred in the onclicklistener and this is the error I'm getting when the onclicklistener has started

Comment: As per you JSON parsing you have to do first pass JSONArray's response to JSONObject and then try to get the solder response from JSONObject.

Comment: @Shashanth: JSONArray jsonObject = new JSONArray(); gives me error when I use getString says "getString(int) in json array cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this part:

```
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonobect = new JSONArray();
```

to

```
JSONObject jsonobject = response.getJSONObject(0);
```